# Python coverage is installing without C extension on Windows under python 3.8, but not under python 3.7, how do I force the C extension version?

Tags: python, coverage.py

I have python 3.7.5 and Python 3.8 installed on the same windows 10 machine. They were both installed from python.org/downloads. When I run pip install coverage (using the latest release of pip) it installs coverage with c extensions under 3.7.5 and without c extensions under 3.8.2.

How can I force coverage to install with c extensions, as the performance is terrible without them?

It appears 3.7.5 downloads:
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4b/c7/6b1af1c8806fa047469b19861a3438f9ce785aa41c831c15d676ccaaa726/coverage-5.0.3-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl

where as 3.8.2 downloads:
coverage-5.0.3.tar.gz

The later being "without c extensions"

Comment: What version did you install? I see that coverage.py [has Windows binary wheels available](https://pypi.org/project/coverage/#files), including for both 3.7 and 3.8 (and even 3.9!), so perhaps just *reinstall*?

Comment: Originally I installed using poetry, then I installed using pip. Both installed version 5.0.3. When I did so for 3.7 it installed version 4.5.4

Comment: Try running `pip install --force-reinstall --only-binary :all: -v coverage` to demand that a binary (wheel) distribution is picked, and let you know, in minute detail, what pip is finding and deciding.

Comment: Right, 4.5.4 did *not* have 3.8 wheels, not for Windows anyway.

Comment: also, running `pip install` with no switches will not upgrade an already installed older version. If 4.5.x is installed, you won't get the 5.0.x release with a 3.8 wheels.

Comment: Last but not least, you can always see if [Gohlke has build wheels for a given package](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/), and he [indeed has coverage wheels available](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#coverage).

Comment: So I clean installed to a windows machine python 3.7.5, ran 
`pip install coverage --no-cache-dir`
It downloaded "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4b/c7/6b1af1c8806fa047469b19861a3438f9ce785aa41c831c15d676ccaaa726/coverage-5.0.3-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl"
Which has c extensions
Did the same for 3.8.2 it downloaded "coverage-5.0.3.tar.gz" without c extensions.

Comment: pip install --force-reinstall --only-binary :all: -v coverage does not work " No matching distribution found for coverage"

Comment: Ah, I think I see what's going on. The wheels available are built with the `--with-pymalloc` switch on, so they are listed as `cp38m`, rather than `cp38`. You are probably using a version without that switch, so the ABI won't work.

Comment: You can verify this with `pip debug --verbose`, which lists all the various wheel tags that'll be accepted. Grep that list for `cp38m`.

Comment: You are correct 3.8 does not have the cp38m in the debug output. However, https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/6874 suggests that the m flag should no longer exist in 3.8 wheels. Does this mean the wheel is incorrectly defined in coverage repo, or am I misunderstanding this?

Comment: Right, in that case it is the [coverage.py build process](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/nedbat/coveragepy/builds/31073003/job/rullse221dd667yn#L346) that is getting this wrong. Can you try to download the file [directly from PyPI](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6a/69/6f21ee32848b03203b3e7c2a6f2fe6827a90d06ebe92ba4a24ac0ed158f3/coverage-5.0.3-cp38-cp38m-win_amd64.whl), renaming the wheel file from `*-cp38-cp38m-*` to `*-cp38-cp38-*` and then using `pip install path/to/local/file.whl`?

Comment: renaming the file (removing the m) does allow successful installation of coverage through pip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no valid `coverage` wheel for Windows and Python 3.8 at the moment.

The [5.0.3 wheels on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/coverage/5.0.3/#files) are marked as compatible with `cp38-cp38m-win_amd64`, so CPython 3.8, with the `cp38m` ABI variant, for 64-bit Windows.

But, there is no such ABI variant any more. Python 3.8 no longer has a `m` (`--with-pymalloc`) binary variant, because [builds with or without `--with-pymalloc` are now ABI compatible](https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.8.html#build-and-c-api-changes).

Pip has followed suit and [stopped adding the `m` flag when looking for wheels](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6885), and the `wheel` project, which *creates* these distribution files [also dropped the `m` flag](https://github.com/pypa/wheel/pull/303).

However, `coverage.py` is using an [older release of `wheel` to build the distributions](https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/blob/1148bf9118f9df3458cae933601a2638e0684218/requirements/wheel.pip#L8), they are using `0.33.1`, while the above changes landed in [version 0.33.5](https://github.com/pypa/wheel/compare/0.33.4...0.33.5). You already [filed a bug report with the project](https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/issues/949), I've added my findings there too.

Luckily, the flag is superficial. You can download the wheel file directly from PyPI, *rename* the file (removing the `m` from `cp38m`) and then use `pip install path/to/renamed/coverage-5.0.3-cp38-cp38m-win_amd64.whl`.

Note: the same issue applies to the 3.9 wheels.